# Is it always best to build a python app into a wheel?

Tags: python

So far I've used two approaches for distributing python code:

- If it's just one script I zip it with a Readme and a req.txt file. I know that ignores versioning but usually that was not relevant. It was more important to make the script available to colleagues with some instructions
- For bigger things I used a proper `src/` structure with `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml`, build a wheel, and distributed that wheel

Now I'm building a web app for the first time and I'm wondering if it still makes sense to build a wheel for it. For the versioning and dependency management it's definitely helpful but it comes with some drawbacks I think.

- I need it to be installable only to make use of clear import statements. But since this is not necessarily meant to be imported by anyone else an editable install would be just as fine. However, it seems wrong to have a production installation "editable" (although technically, every python installation is editable)
- It makes launching certain parts harder. E.g. for `uvicorn` I would need to either navigate into the venv lib directory or include a startup programmatically with all possible startup options considered
- Likewise, if I want to start a task handler like `celery` or `dramatiq` I need a long command into the lib directory to launch it instead of launching it where the files are nice and visible

Of course these are all problems that can be dealt with. These components shall be run as a `service` anyway, so I can put the venv lib paths in there. And since it's all gonna run on a VM that I manage I can take care of that easily.

I'm just wondering if that's really the way to go for self-managed deployment or if there is a cleaner approach.

I'm also aware that this is a general question, but I would be grateful for some tips or references since I can't shake the feeling that this is clunky but I also couldn't find a better approach online.

Comment: I think you are really talking about creating a distribution package or not. Whether the distribution is in the form of a wheel or something that will build architecture-specific components local during installation is another matter.

Comment: Hm yea. I just have a hard time wrapping my head around how to distribute a web app since I never built one before. I only built stuff that's perfectly fine to make into a wheel and get this to the users.
Do you have any recommendations where to read up on best practices for that? Because if I search for deployment I usually just find stuff on cloud services etc. but not best practices that focus on just the python part.

Comment: Packaging and deployment are two separate things. Packaging in this context just means building something that you could upload to PyPi (or your own local package repository). Once you do that, you can *install* the package in a virtual environment, in a Docker container, or however else you will be *deploying* your code. I would start by browsing https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html.